# Custom Formatting of JSON output using Spark

Tags: json, apache-spark, jackson

I have a dataset with a bunch of BigDecimal values. I would like to output these records to a JSON file, but when I do the BigDecimal values will often be written with trailing zeros (`123.4000000000000`), but the spec we are must conform to does not allow this (for reasons I don't understand).

I am trying to see if there is a way to override how the data is printed to JSON.
Currently, my best idea is to convert each record to a string using JACKSON and then writing the data using `df.write().text(..)` rather than JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to convert Decimal type to String before writing to JSON.

Below code is in Scala, but you can use it in Java easily

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType

# COLUMN_NAME is your DataFrame column name.

val new_df = df.withColumn('COLUMN_NAME_TMP', df.COLUMN_NAME.cast(StringType)).drop('COLUMN_NAME').withColumnRenamed('COLUMN_NAME_TMP', 'COLUMN_NAME')
```